# ¿Cómo cojo tantos número como indico con un parámetro?

Tags: python, bucles, while

Estoy tratando de crear un programa que pida una cantidad de números , el primer problema es que siempre me pide dos números de más, el segundo es que no cuenta los números negativos , de momento este es el código:

```
n = int(input("Cuantos numeros: "))
numeros = int(input("Numeros: "))
contador = 0
numerosn = ""

while contador <= n:
    numeros = int(input("Numeros: "))

    contador += 1


    if numeros < 0:
        numerosn += str(numeros)
        print("Los numeros negativoss son: ",numerosn)
```

El resultado de momento es este. No sé por qué no cuenta el primer número negativo y al final debería de imprimir otra vez todos los números negativos solamente:

```
Cuantos numeros: 5
Numeros: -7
Numeros: 5
Numeros: -4
Els numeros negatius son:  -4
Numeros: -6
Els numeros negatius son:  -4-6
Numeros: -2
Els numeros negatius son:  -4-6-2
Numeros: -3
Els numeros negatius son:  -4-6-2-3
Numeros: 1
```

Comment: muestras lo que da actualmente, pero ¿qué quieres que dé exactamente? Dale también a [edit] para ajustar el formato, la sentencia dentro del `while` debe estar identada para que funcione

Comment: Un error es que siempre le pido 5 numeros y me deja pedir 7 numeros y no se porque, el siguiente error es que el primer numero negativo -7 no lo suma a la lista

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quieres pedirle un número y que te pida esa cantidad de números.

En concreto, introduces un entero `n` y controlas con `contador` y un `while`:

```
contador = 0
while contador <= n:
    contador += 1
```

Veamos la lógica con detenimiento:

| n | contador | contador <= n |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | sí |
| 0 | 1 | no |

Así, si le das `n=0` te entrará en el bucle 1 vez y, por tanto, acabarás cogiendo 1 número en total. Y si le das `n=1` entrará 2 veces.

Además, tienes una línea `numeros = int(input("Numeros: "))` antes de entrar en el bucle, por lo que acabas cogiendo `n+2` números.

Por tanto, tocaría inicializar `contador` a 1 o bien hacer `while contador < n`, así como quitar la línea `numeros = int(input("Numeros: "))`.

> No sé por qué no cuenta el primer número negativo

No cuenta el primer número negativo porque lo has leído antes del bucle y no lo has guardado en ningún sitio.

> al final debería de imprimir otra vez todos los números negativos solamente

Solo imprimes si se entra en el `if numeros<0`, por lo que si el último número introducido no es negativo, no imprimes. Tal vez quieras añadir un `print` después del bucle.